# LINQ to select the last input in a table from every day

Tags: c#, database, linq

The table updates every 5 minutes so each day has multiple inputs.
I have a couple of include but they are not important since the date is just in one of the tables. My LINQ knowledge is very shallow. 
How do i ask for the last input of every day? The datatype is DateTime.
Right now I'm asking the database for the last 15000 inputs and then filter them with a bunch of for loops. It works but is not sustainable and very slow. 
Thankful for every bit of help that can be provided!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Group by the day component of your date (see [DateTime.Date](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date(v=vs.110).aspx))

2- For each group, order all items by their dates (which already belong to the same day) and then select the maximum.

```
List<EntityClass> list = new List<EntityClass>();

list.GroupBy(e => e.date.Date) // 1
       .Select(grp => grp.OrderBy(e => e.date).Last()); //2
```